# I can't insert a new record without it FK already existing in its own table

Tags: database, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I am trying to add a new record into 2 tables (using FK) at the same time, I had it working for me quite well but when I changed the FK to ON UPDATE: CASCADE, something happened. It allows me to insert a new record only if the clients name and phone number already exist in the clients table, that means it won't let me add a new one. When I try to use a different phone number it won't show me any errors.

Here how my reservation and client tables look like.

**reservation**:
id(PK), num, location, diners, re_date, re_time, phonenumber(FK)

**clients**:
fullname, phonenumber(PK)

***Controller***

```
//form to save new reservation
public function create() {  

        $newDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->input->post('re_date')));
        $newTime = date("H:i", strtotime($this->input->post('re_time')));
        $data = array(
            'num' => $this->input->post('num'),
            'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
            'diners' => $this->input->post('diners'),
            're_date' => $newDate,
            're_time' => $newTime,
            'phonenumber' => $this->input->post('phonenumber'),
        );

        $dataclient = array( 
            'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
            'phonenumber' => $this->input->post('phonenumber'),
        );

        $this->Hosting_model->form_insert($data, $dataclient);
        redirect(base_url("/hosting/tableMap"));

    }
```

***Model***

```
public function form_insert($data, $dataclient){
            $this->db->db_debug = FALSE;
             $error = NULL;
             if (!( ($this->db->insert('reservations', $data)) && ($this->db->insert('clients', $dataclient)))) {
                 $error = $this->db->error();
             }
             return $error;
        }
```

Comment: Looks like this has nothing to do with the `ON Update Cascade`, but more about the relationship of your tables. Your `FK` column in reservations references the client table and therefore should be throwing an error if you try to insert a non existing `FK` (primary key in client table).

Comment: Okay thank you for responding, it's quite weird though cause I've worked with it before, can you explain or suggest a solution because I can't fully understand.

Comment: Table `reservations` column `phonenumber` -> links the record to the `client` table using it's primary key `phonenumber`, if you try to insert a record into `reservations` with a phone number which doesn't exist, it can't link that record with the `client` table. This is part of the relational table design. Now, if the `phonenumber` column in `reservations` is `nullable` you could insert a record into `reservations` with a `null` value in the `phonenumber` column.

Comment: Thank you. So I've changed the relation of them both by setting the phonenumber of the clients table to a unique index and added a different primary key and now I assigned it as an FK, but still, it doesn't work. I understand what you've said, it was my misunderstanding.